# wavefront .obj file loader problem

Tags: c++, directx11

I'm pretty new to direct x and c++, I have a problem with loading .obj files.

This is a cube
[image]

I think the problem is with creating vertices and indecies.

```
list<vertex> FinalVertices;

list<unsigned long> Indecies;
for (int i = 0; i < Faces.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Faces.size(); j++)
    {
        if (Faces[i] == Faces[j])
        {
            cout << 'b' << endl;
            if (i == j) 
            {
                FinalVertices.push_back(Faces[i]);
                Indecies.push_back(j);
            }
            goto a;
        }
    }
a:
    cout << ' ';
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [WaveFrontReader.h](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXMesh/blob/master/Utilities/WaveFrontReader.h). You may also want to look at [DirectX Tool Kit for DX11](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn That's not fun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're adding an index only when you encounter a new unique vertex. You want to add the index for repeated vertices too, so move that line outside the `if (i==j)` block.

```
if (Faces[i] == Faces[j]) { 
    cout << 'b' << endl;
    if (i == j) { 
        FinalVertices.push_back(Faces[i]);
     } 
     Indecies.push_back(j);
     goto a; 
}
```